# compressing the file using SevenZipSharp.dll

Tags: vb.net, compression, sevenzipsharp

I want to compress and move the file using `vb.net` and `SevenZipSharp.dll`

`c:\Backup\FULLBackup.bak -> c:\Archive\20130322.7z`

I added a reference SevenZipSharp.dll

```
Imports SevenZip   

SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\SevenZipSharp.dll")

Dim theCompressor As New SevenZipCompressor()
            With theCompressor
                .ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.SevenZip
                .CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Create
                .CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Default
                .DirectoryStructure = False
                .CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Normal
            End With

theCompressor.CompressFilesEncrypted("c:\Archive\20130322.7z","c:\Backup\FULLBackup.bak")
```

I get an error : `Can not load 7-zip library or internal COM error! Message: library is invalid.`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply the fact that the LibraryPath must not point to "**SevenZipSharp.dll**" but to "**7z.dll**".
http://blog.jongallant.com/2011/10/7-zip-dll-file-does-not-exist.html#.UaOLk0DxobA